# Rename [clash-in-the-clouds] → [bioshock-infinite-clash-in-clouds]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Since we have a 35 character tag limit now, the tag for *Bioshock Infinite: Clash in the Clouds* should be expanded. Unfortunately, [bioshock-infinite-clash-in-the-clouds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioshock-infinite-clash-in-the-clouds) is two characters too long, so I think the best we can do is:

- [clash-in-the-clouds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clash-in-the-clouds) → [bioshock-infinite-clash-in-clouds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioshock-infinite-clash-in-clouds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done:

- [clash-in-the-clouds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clash-in-the-clouds) → [bioshock-infinite-clash-in-clouds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioshock-infinite-clash-in-clouds)